# Missing constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I was confused why my program behaved in an unexpected way. Then I wrote this simplified version of it and discovered that there is a constructor call "missing".

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:

    A () {std::cout << "default" << "\n";}  // default ctor

    A (const A& src)                        // copy ctor
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << "\n";
    }

    friend A<T> operator<<(A& a, unsigned i)
    {
        std::cout << "x1" << "\n";
        A tmp;
        std::cout << "x2" << "\n";
        return tmp;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A<int> a1;
    A<int> a2(a1 << 2);
}
```

Output

```
default
x1
default
x2
```

What I had expected was

```
default
x1
default
x2
copy
```

as the r-value returned by `a1 << 2` would be passed into the `const A&` parameter of the copy ctor. But that is not what happens. And if not that then at least I would expect

```
default
x1
default
x2
default
```

because I would have thought that the constructor for `a2` would need to be called.

What is going on here?

Comment: Copy elision. I think that compiling without optimization should do it.

Comment: I read about that but to me that still did not explain why not even the variant with the 3 default calls is the case.

Comment: And I am not compiling with optimization anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong with the optimization part

Comment: Because copy elision.

Comment: @lotolmencre *And I am not compiling with optimization anyway*  -- This has no bearing on whether the compiler will decide to elide copies or not.

Comment: @lotolmencre *I was confused why my program behaved in an unexpected way* -- Well, if that "unexpected way" led to a bug, then the moral of the story is not to write copy constructors that have side-effects.  A copy constructor's job is to make a copy, and not really to perform important business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of **copy elision**. More specifically, **N**amed **R**eturn **V**alue **O**ptimization, or NRVO.

NRVO happens when a local (to the function) variable with automatic storage duration is returned by value from a function, and that value is assigned to a variable:

```
friend A<T> operator<<(A& a, unsigned i)
{
    //...
    A tmp; //automatic storage variable 
    //...
    return tmp; //returned by value
}

A<int> a2(a1 << 2); //Assigned to a2
```

The compiler is allowed to elide the copy of `tmp` to `a2`. This basically means that when the function ends, *the memory of `tmp` is not deallocated!* Then, it just assigns `a2` to that memory location, which basically results in a "copy" of `tmp`.

This happens if even the copy/move constructors and destructor have side-effects, like outputting some value. Due note however that this is implementation defined, some compiler might as well output the second and/or the third case.

For other forms of copy elision, refer to [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).